# Updating state arrays with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an form with radio inputs. Each time the user selects on option, I must update the array containing the answers to the questions overriding old answers if it is the same question the user answered. So I have this `useState` 
that, in my thought, would map the old values of answers, map if the answer to the question is already there and `Object.assign()` it, otherwise if it is a new answer to a new question, then just return the answer. But it only returns the default array. If it is initialized like [{}] it returns `Array[{}]`. If it is [], returns `Array[]`

State is
    `const [answers, setAnswers] = setState([])`

```js
  const handleCheckbox = (e, question) => {
    const newAnswer = { choice: e.target.id, question: question.uuid };

    setAnswers(
      [...answers],
      answers.map(
        answer =>
          answer.question === newAnswer.question ?
          Object.assign(answer, newAnswer): 
          newAnswer
      )
    );
  };
```

Expected: `answers: [{id: 1}, {id: 2},...]` without repeating those already there.

Actual: `Array[]`

Comment: You cannot create an array with this shape [answerQuestion1: {}, answerQuestion2:{},...]. Maybe more code will help us understand the issue better. A codesandbox will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, you are calling the updater `setAnswers` with 2 arguments whereas it take a single one. Your exepected result `[answerQuestion1: {}, answerQuestion2:{},...]` is not valid JSON format and you used `setState` instead of `useState`.

I think you should restructure your model, why not use an object for the state variable `answers`, it would be like this :

```
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({});

const handleCheckbox = (e, question) => {
  const id = question.uuid;
  const value = e.target.id; // Maybe you could use e.target.value or e.target.name

  setAnswers(prevAnswers => ({
     ...prevAnswers,
     [id]: value
  }));
};
```

Comment: Yes. I've mistyped setState() instead o useState(). The original code is right.

Comment: It works! But still have a slightly problem. When the event is triggered the first time, the object remains empty, only after the first triggering it updates de object with actual values.

Comment: I don't really understant what is the problem ? you mean the first event doesn't update the state variable ? How did you check that ? Maybe the problem comes from the code which produces the rendering ?

Comment: I'm using id because of the structure of my choice object. Choices are unique. The e.target.value repeat over other questions, but I could use e.target.name. Is there a specific reason to use value or name instead of id?

Comment: My mistake. I was calling console.log(answers) inside handleCheckbox. I think the console.log was being executed before the state could update, returning the old value.

Comment: be aware that `setAnswers` is asynchronous. If you add a `console.log` just after the `setAnswers`, you will not see the updated answers